# Unable to Create ZIPfile using python

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-zipfile

I am trying to create zipfile using python 3.4.
Upon execution following error is shown:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Zipfile'
```

My code:

```
import zipfile

f= zipfile.Zipfile("testZIP.zip","w")
```

Answer (score 20):

It is `zipfile.ZipFile` with a capital `F` not `zipfile.Zipfile`